# IS active boolean column in MySQL for removing duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, tableau-desktop

I would like to create a column in MySQL named IS active which will be TRUE if the data has a single entry and will be FALSE if the data has a duplicate entry. We use this similar function in Tableau by using the following command.

FIXED caseid : max(visitdate)}=visitdate

Here the caseid is a unique ID and we use visitdate variable. This marks our duplicate entry as False and others as True. It considers duplicate entries using the latest value by visitdate.
How do I make something similar in MySQL.

Comment: Do you need to have that as a column on the table (in that case you can use an insert / update trigger to set the value) or are you just needing that in a query (in which case you can join to the table itself to determine that)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes I need to have it in the table, as a column